# std::string::erase() erases everything after 1st char found with std::string::find()

Tags: c++, string, c++11

I'm still having difficulty to phrase title for this question , take a look at this code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

int main(){
    std::string s1 = " Hello World  1 ";
    std::string s2 = " Hello World  2 ";
    while(s1.find(' ') != std::string::npos){
        s1.erase(s1.find(' '));
    }
    while(s2.find(' ') != std::string::npos){
        s2.erase(std::find(s2.begin() , s2.end() ,' '));
    }
    std::cout<<s1<<"\n";
    std::cout<<s2;
    return 0;
}
```

I'm using `std::string::find()` to detect the presence of whitespace inside string , and if still present , use `std::string::erase()` to delete them.

I've tried two different methods of doing this:

```
s1.erase(s1.find(' '));
```

and

```
s2.erase(std::find(s2.begin() , s2.end() ,' '));
```

however in 1st method , it finds the 1st occurence of `' '` whitespace inside string and deletes it and everything following it. 2nd method works as expected.

Current Output is :

```
HelloWorld2
```

Can anyone tell me what is the reason behind 1st method deleting everything following the 1st occurence? For quick glance : [link](http://ideone.com/gYAwFU)

Relevant links :

[std::basic_string::find](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find)

[std::find](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find)

[std::basic_string::erase](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/erase)

Comment: the standard stl method to remove should be `s1.erase(std::remove(s1.begin(), s1.begin(), value), s1.end())`

Comment: By "ahead of", do you mean from the location of the space to the end of the string?

Comment: `std::string::erase()` accepts both indexes and iterators as parameters.

Comment: @beaker I've added output to answer , and yes. It deletes the whole string if 1st character is a whitespace.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I didn't understand. Can you explain a little bit? Possibly write an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I'm using `std::string::find()` to detect the presence of whitespace inside string , and if still present , use `std::string::erase()` to delete them.

You don't need to call `find()` twice per loop iteration.  Call it once and save the return value to a variable, then check the value of that variable and pass it to `erase()` if needed.

> I've tried two different methods of doing this
>
> ```
> s1.erase(s1.find(' '));
> ```
>
> and
>
> ```
> s2.erase(std::find(s2.begin() , s2.end() ,' '));
> ```
>
> however in 1st method , it finds the 1st occurence of ' ' whitespace inside string and deletes it and everything following it.

Read the [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/erase) you linked to.  You are calling the version of `erase()` that takes an index as its first parameter:

```
basic_string& erase( size_type index = 0, size_type count = npos );
```

When you do not specify a `count` value, it gets set to `npos`, which tells `erase()` to remove *everything* from the `string` starting at the specified `index` to the **end of the string**.  Your `string` starts with a space character, so you are wiping out your *entire string*, that is why it does not appear in the output.

You need to specify a `count` of 1 to remove just the space character that `find()` found:

```
do
{
    std::string size_type pos = s1.find(' ');
    if (pos == std::string::npos)
        break;
    s1.erase(pos, 1); //  <-- erase only one character
}
while (true);
```

Alternatively, you should make use of the second parameter of `find()` so you can start the next loop iteration where the previous iteration left off.  Without that, you are going back to the beginning of the string each time and re-searching characters you have already searched:

```
std::string::size_type pos = 0;
do
{
    pos = s1.find(' ', pos); // <-- begin search at current position
    if (pos == std::string::npos)
        break;
    s1.erase(pos, 1); // <-- erase only one character
}
while (true);
```

Or, if you prefer:

```
std::string::size_type pos = s1.find(' ');
while (pos != std::string::npos)
{
    s1.erase(pos, 1); // <-- erase only one character
    pos = s1.find(' ', pos); // <-- begin search at current position
}
```

> 2nd method works as expected.

You are calling a different version of `erase()`:

```
iterator erase( iterator position );
```

`std::find()` returns an `iterator`.  This version of `erase()` removes just the single character that is pointed at by the iterator.

Comment: Thanks :) , we could also add this with same while loop `std::string s1 = "Hello World  1 ";
 std::string::size_type p = s1.find(' ');
 while(p!= std::string::npos){
  s1.erase(p , 1);
  p = s1.find(' ');
 }`

Comment: @AbhinavGauniyal: You are still going back to the beginning of the string and re-searching the *entire* string on every loop iteration, which is redundant for characters you have already skipped.  Better to avoid that overhead by using the second parameter of `find()`, by changing `p = s1.find(' ')` to `p = s1.find(' ', p)` at the bottom of the loop. I have added that example to my answer.

Comment: Thanks for these helpful edits, I get it now :)  std::basic_string::find too had a overload.

Answer (score 1):

Your call

```
s1.find(' ')
```

returns the position of the first space, which is `0` in your case. You then call

```
s1.erase(s1.find(' ')); // i.e. s1.erase(0);
```

which erases from position `0` to the end of the string, as it invokes the overload

```
basic_string& erase( size_type index = 0, size_type count = npos );
```

number 1 [from here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/erase).
If you pass `1` instead of the default `npos`

```
s1.erase(s1.find(' '), 1); // pass 1 instead of default npos
```

then it works as expected.

Comment: I never saw the default parameters :(. Thanks +1.

Answer (score 1):

> Can anyone tell me what is the reason behind 1st method deleting
>   everything ahead of 1st occurence?

*`std::basic_string::find`* returns position ( *`size_type`* ) of the first character of the found substring or *`std::string::npos`*

Therefore, *`s1.erase(s1.find(' '));`* will simply erase from position **0** to the **end** of the string. Notice the first loop executes only once !